# TS Error on JEST Testing - SelectOptions.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am having a simple utility, in which I am returning a boolean, based on some comparing functionality:

```
import ISelect from './interfaces/ISelect';

const checkCaseSensitiveSelectUtil = (inputValue: ISelect, selectOptions: ISelect[]): boolean => {
  const exactValueExists = selectOptions.find(input => input.value === inputValue.value);
  return !exactValueExists;
};

export default checkCaseSensitiveSelectUtil;
```

And here is my test:

```
  it('should return TRUE if the values are equal', () => {
    const selectedOptions = {
      label: '*positions',
      value: '*positions'
    };
    expect(checkCaseSensitiveSelectUtil(caseInsensitiveValues, selectedOptions)).toEqual(true);
  });
```

And here is what I am getting as an error:

```
    TypeError: selectOptions.find is not a function

      2 |
      3 | const checkCaseSensitiveSelectUtil = (inputValue: ISelect, selectOptions: ISelect[]): boolean => {
    > 4 |   const exactValueExists = selectOptions.find(input => input.value === inputValue.value);
        |                                          ^
      5 |   return !exactValueExists;
      6 | };
      7 |
```

Any idea about what to do? I mean the whole thing is working properly. But what am I having wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `find` function exist for arrays and not object.

```
const selectedOptions = {
  label: '*positions',
  value: '*positions'
};
```

Change the above to a valid array object.

Try this

```
const selectedOptions = [{
  label: '*positions',
  value: '*positions'
}];
```